# Active Admin new button disappeared

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

i'm setting up active admin and for some reason my "New Question" button has disappeared.  This is what the file looks like.

```
    ActiveAdmin.register Question do
      menu priority: 4
      permit_params :list, :of, :attributes, :on, :question, :question, :extra_info, :topic_id, :question_image, :question_image_name, :extra_info_image, :extra_image_name

      # ...
      form :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|
        inputs 'Question' do
          input :question
          input :extra_info
          input :topic,  :as => :select,      :collection => Topic.pluck(:name, :id)
          input :question_image, :as => :file
          input :extra_info_image, :as => :file
        end
        para "Press cancel to return to the list without saving."
        actions
      end
      show do |question|
        attributes_table do
          row :id
          row :question
          row :extra_info
          row :topic
          row :question_image do
            image_tag(question.question_image.url)
          end
          row :extra_info_image do
            image_tag(question.extra_info_image.url)
          end
        end
        panel "Answers" do
         question.answers.by_id.each do |answer|
           h3 li "#{answer.answer_text} | (#{answer.count})"
         end
       end
      end
    end
```

[image]

I've tried deleting the code and making it just the default view, and still no luck.

Comment: Are you using cancancan?

Comment: Is the button just visually hidden or it doesn't exist in DOM?

Comment: Only get secure, do you use cancan or pundit. Do you have a ability or policy named file in your Project?